# jquery setting correct height for content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've set up a div that stores text with a nice gradient fade at the bottom with a show hide button.  I found this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/) to help me do that, and for the most part i've managed to get it working for my needs.

However, I'm having an issue where when i have a rather long bit of text. When showing the text, it cuts off the bottom of the text.  By doing a `console.log($("#id).height());` it appears that it's picking up the div's max-height from the CSS rather than the height of the actual content (but i could be wrong).

I've set up a JSFiddle with my example: http://jsfiddle.net/3gnK7/4/ you'll notice that by clicking the **Show** button on the first part, the last para of the lorem ipsum text is cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does add a requirement of jqueryUI to get the animation however it works completely

first change your css to

```
.category_text {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    max-height: 120px;

}

.cat-height {
    max-height: 9999px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

then change your javascript to use [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showbutton").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var buttonid = $(this).attr("id");
        buttonid = buttonid.substring(11, buttonid.length);

        $("#text_"+buttonid).toggleClass('cat-height','slow');

        if($("#showbutton_" + buttonid).text() == 'Show') {
           $("#showbutton_" + buttonid).text("Hide");
        }
        else {
            $("#showbutton_" + buttonid).text("Show");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3gnK7/11/)

Comment: This works perfectly, though for whatever reason jQueryUI is added in the footer to our sites (or at least below where this script is being added)... is there a way of using jQuerys delay or other methods to acheive the same effect?

Comment: @Jarede on a side note if you don't wish to use JQueryUI you could utilise CSS3 transitions and rely on the standard JQuery toggleClass

Answer (score 1):

```
   totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
```

True argument will include margins, too.